# I can not get string value in php

Tags: string, path, get

My php file location is

```
http://localhost/mysite-Copy/index.php
```

Here is link to go other page

```
http://localhost/mysite-Copy/category/Article/money1.php
```

And in this link I can not get string value when I use code `$_Get['id']`

I can not get string value in this link

```
http://localhost/mysite-Copy/category/Article/money1.php
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: When and where are you passing your "id" value to money1.php?

Answer (score 1):

As your question is really unclear, I guess that you forgot to pass your "id" value into your money1.php, by calling

`http://localhost/mysite-Copy/category/Article/money1.php?id=your_id_here`

And then get it back in your money1.php with `$value = $_GET["id"]`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Big00d. Also, the problem may lie in your html form. You do realise we can't browse to those **local** links, right?